# UITableview not scrolling smoothly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have UITableView in my application & have created tableview cell normally with creating any class file.
In my table cell i'm adding UITextview due to which my UITableView is " **not scrolling smoothly** ".
After I **comment textview code or replaces textview with textfield/Label** then tableview scroll as smoothly as it should .

Can anyone tell me why this is is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Here is how i'm adding textview in table :

```
    UITextView *txtview = [[UITextView alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(93.0,36.0,190.0,94.0)];            
    txtview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    txtview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strText];
    txtview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5 ,0 ,0 ,0); 
    txtview.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:221.0/255.0 green:249.0/255.0
    blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];   
    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtview];
    [txtview release];
```

Here is my Cell generation code :

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    if (!cell) 
        cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    else
    {
      NSArray *arraySubviews = [cell.contentView subviews];

        for (UIView *views in arraySubviews)
        {
            [views removeFromSuperview];

        }
    }
```

Comment: do you using cell reusing? paste cell generation code here.

Comment: @NeverBe :have posted my cell generation code....

Comment: @vishy:txtShout was mistake from my side...have updated my code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cell =(UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];  

        if (nil ==cell) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];    
            UITextView *txtview = [[UITextView alloc]
                                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(93.0,36.0,190.0,94.0)];            
            txtview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            txtview.tag = 15;

            txtview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5 ,0 ,0 ,0); 
            txtview.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:221.0/255.0 green:249.0/255.0
                                                 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];   
            [cell.contentView addSubview:txtShout];
            [txtview release];
        }
        UITextView *txtview = (UITextView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:15];
        txtview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strText];
```

Comment: @Sanjeev:Great!!!,your solution is working like charm...that helped me solve my problem....